# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project marks application as requiring elevation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment

**EDIT:** I would still like an answer to this question if anyone can provide one, however I have decided to split out the non-administrative part of this project into another project which will call this project as required.

I have a project which manipulates some registry keys under HKLM - which obviously requires elevation. The application knows when it needs this elevation and will re-launch itself with `runas` to get elevation.

In the development environment this works fine, and the application also runs fine on intended targets in this form.

When I pump the project through a VS2010 setup project and install the project on the target system, the EXE gets marked as requiring elevation and requests it whenever it gets run before the application logic determines if it needs it.

I have searched for an hour or so and found nothing which relates, though I suspect the power of my search terms is insufficiently strong (or I lack the right ones) to find an appropriate result.

How can I stop the setup project from marking the executable as requiring elevation?

---

Subsequent to the comment below I added a custom manifest to the project with the same result, the manifest looked right to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Here's the output of the project's build (in the obj folder since that's what's being pulled in by the setup project):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/elrQh.png

The outwardly obvious thing is the lack of the UAC shield on the executable. After building the setup project, then installing it via the resultant MSI, the installed executable is like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A33qz.png

Noting the now existing UAC shield.

Before adding the custom manifest, it was set to use a default one (which I suspect has the same content).

Comment: Hmm, no, Setup projects don't do this.  Review the manifest embedded in the program and make sure Visual Studio isn't running elevated which would hide the problem.

Comment: When running in debug the program behaves as expected (detects it lacks elevation and then re-launches).

Comment: Oh, and Visual Studio is not running elevated. I tried addding a manifest - edited question to reflect.